# How do I zero pad in hql

Tags: hql

I have the following query

```
final StringBuffer hql = new StringBuffer()
.append("select p.productDetails from Product as p WHERE lower(p.sku || ' ' || p.productDetails.name) like lower(:filter)");
```

The user should be able to type in a filter on a web form that is sent to the back end. The filter may be part of the sku or the name. the sku is stored as an Integer in the database, and therefore leading zeros don't exist, but the user may type in the leading zeros. Currently when the user types 00185 it will find 200185, but not 001852.

How do I zero pad the "p.sku"?

Comment: Why don't you unpad the filter, and use `where p.sku like :unpaddedFilter or lower(p.productDetails.name) like lower(:filter)`

Comment: Then when someone searches for 00185 they'll get things like 4185.

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of using a like? If you want an exact match, just use where `p.sku = :unpaddedFilter`

Comment: No. When a user types 00185 they expect to find 200185 and 001852 but not 1185, 2185, 3185, etc.

Comment: Then it's quite strange to expect  finding 1852 when typing 00185. There is no 00 in 1852. Maybe you shouldn't store these as numbers, but as strings, with the leading 0s. Just like phone numbers which, despite being composed of digits, are not really numbers.

Comment: What I have to work with, is what I have to work with. I'm not architecting the database.